# Merging multiple rows of data into same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml-path

I would like to create a table of job ids and a column listing all the different job categories that get matched up, but concatenated into the same column. As an example, right now job 82041 has two categories, but now is returning two rows. I would like for it to say "Retail, Sales Associate", all in one field.

The code that I tried is below, can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

EXAMPLE:

```
jobOrderID  (No column name)

82027    Motion Graphics               
82029    Other                         
82030    Product Designer              
82041    Retail                        
82041    Sales Associate               
82069    Social Media
```

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
select  JobOrder.jobOrderID ,    
        stuff((select distinct ', ' + cast(Category.occupation as nchar(30)) 
               from Category 
                where Category.categoryID = JobOrderCategories.categoryID
        for xml path ('')),1,1,'')    

from JobOrder 
left outer join JobOrderCategories 
     on JobOrder.joborderid = JobOrderCategories.jobOrderID
left outer join Category 
     on Category.categoryID = JobOrderCategories.categoryID

where JobOrder.dateAdded > '2017-5-2' and JobOrder.dateAdded < '2017-5-3'
  and joborder.isDeleted = 0

order by joborder.dateAdded asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by altering the left joins

```
select

JobOrder.jobOrderID,

stuff((select distinct ', ' + cast(Category.occupation as varchar(30)) 
from Category 
left outer join JobOrderCategories on (Category.categoryID = JobOrderCategories.categoryID and joborder.jobOrderID = JobOrderCategories.joborderid)
where Category.categoryID = JobOrderCategories.categoryID
for xml path ('')),1,1,'')


from JobOrder 

where JobOrder.dateAdded > '2017-5-2' and JobOrder.dateAdded < '2017-5-3'
and joborder.isDeleted = 0
```